# async let does not compile because of the "Reference to captured var 'imageDescriptors' in concurrently-executing code"

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency

I am trying to use withThrowingTaskGroup to get some data from the web. I found that my code runs a bit slow, so I tried to use actors with async/await. I use Descriptors to get the

```
func getAllStocksList() async throws -> [SingleStockViewModel] {
    var stockViewModels = [SingleStockViewModel]()
    let urlString = URLBuilder.getAllStocks.makeString()
    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: urlString)!)
    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
        throw "Invalid HttpResponseCode"
    }
    let dataResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode([StockDetails].self, from: data)
    let stocksDetailsList = dataResponse[..<25]
    let stockSymbolsList = stocksDetailsList.map {
        $0.title
    }
    let dataResponseDict = dataResponse.toDictionary {
        $0.title
    }

    var stockPrices: [String: Double] = [:]
    let imageUrlStringsDict = try await imageService.makeStockImageUrlStringsList(for: stockSymbolsList)
    let nonEmptyImageUrlStringsList = imageUrlStringsDict.filter {
        !$0.value.isEmpty
    }
    var imageDescriptors = [Descriptor]()
    var chartDescriptors = [Descriptor]()
    for item in nonEmptyImageUrlStringsList {
        imageDescriptors.append(
                Descriptor(
                        stockSymbol: item.key,
                        stockImageUrlString: nonEmptyImageUrlStringsList[item.key]!,
                        type: .image)
        )
        chartDescriptors.append(
                Descriptor(stockSymbol: item.key,
                        stockImageUrlString: "",
                        type: .marketData)
        )
        let price = try await fetchStockPrice(for: item.key)
        stockPrices[item.key] = price
    }

    print(chartDescriptors)
    async let taskResults = try fetchGroupedStocksInfo(descriptors: imageDescriptors)
    async let marketDataTaskResult = try fetchGroupedStocksInfo(descriptors: chartDescriptors)
    let (taskResultsDict, marketDataTaskResultDict) = try await (taskResults, marketDataTaskResult)
}
```

and the stock descriptor is passed to

```
func fetchGroupedStocksInfo(descriptors: [Descriptor]) async throws -> [String: TaskResult] {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: (String, TaskResult).self, returning: [String: TaskResult].self) { group in
        for descriptor in descriptors {
            group.addTask { [self] in
                switch descriptor.type {
                case .image:
                    let (_, image) = try await self.imageService.makeStockImageTuple(descriptor.stockImageUrlString)
                    let (symbol, marketResponse) = try await merketInfoSerice.fetchMarketInfo(descriptor.stockSymbol, numberOfDays: 3)
                    print(image)
                    return (descriptor.stockSymbol, TaskResult.image(image))
                case .marketData:
                    let (symbol, marketResponse) = try await merketInfoSerice.fetchMarketInfo(descriptor.stockSymbol, numberOfDays: 3)
                    print(marketResponse.close)
                    return (symbol, TaskResult.marketData(marketResponse))
                }
            }
        }
        return try await group.reduce(into: [:]) {
            $0[$1.0] = $1.1
        }
    }
}
```

and the errors found in compile time are

```
(63, 73) Reference to captured var 'imageDescriptors' in concurrently-executing code
(64, 82) Reference to captured var 'chartDescriptors' in concurrently-executing code
```

How can I make these error disappear, though I sense that my code can cause some problems at runtime.

Comment: Please post an example that compiles. Lot of the code is missing. It's always best to provide a simplified example so that it is easier to have a look

Answer (score 3):

You received this error:

> Reference to captured var 'imageDescriptors' in concurrently-executing code

The issue is that you are supplying a mutable array to `async let`, an expression that will be `await`’ed later. As [SE-0317 async let bindings](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md) says:

> The right-hand side of a `async let` expression can be thought of as an implicit `@Sendable closure` ... the closure is `@Sendable` and `nonisolated`, meaning that it cannot access non-sendable state of the enclosing context.

Bottom line, the problem goes away if you replace it with an immutable array.

1. You can initialize them to constants directly:

   ```swift
   let imageDescriptors = items.map { item in
       Descriptor(
           stockSymbol: item.key,
           stockImageUrlString: nonEmptyImageUrlStringsList[item.key]!,
           type: .image
       )
   }

   let chartDescriptors = items.map { item in
       Descriptor(
           stockSymbol: item.key,
           stockImageUrlString: "",
           type: .marketData
       )
   }
   ```
2. You can make your own copy:

   ```swift
   let descriptors = imageDescriptors
   async let taskResults = try fetchGroupedStocksInfo(descriptors: descriptors)
   ```
3. Instead of `async let`, you can make your own `Task` with an explicit capture list:

   ```swift
   let subtask1 = Task { [imageDescriptors] in
       await self.fetchGroupedStocksInfo(descriptors: imageDescriptors)
   }
   let subtask2 = Task { [chartDescriptors] in
       await try fetchGroupedStocksInfo(descriptors: chartDescriptors)
   }

   let (taskResultsDict, marketDataTaskResultDict) = try await (subtask1.value, subtask2.value)
   ```

   NB: This opts out of structured concurrency.